# ID3-метаданные

Tags: c++builder, аудио, mp3, c++

Есть ли какие-то открытые алгоритмы/библиотеки для редактирования `ID3`-информации (от `ID3v1` до `ID3v2.4`) в `MP3`-файлах?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужен [id3lib](http://id3lib.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Спасибо, именно то, что я искал.